# How to send email with Powershell, only when certain variable are not empty?

Tags: powershell

How to modify the below script, so it does not send the email when certain variables are empty?

Note: These variable **($volumes) -and ($ResultEvents) -and ($services)** was part of the bigger script which contains Disk VOlume Info, Event Logs and Services list, if they are a match of certain filter.

```
   $sendMailArgs['Body'] = $null
   
   If ($volumes | Where-Object { ($_.'Free Space (%)'.ToDouble($cultureInfo) -lt $warnPercent) -and ($_.Label -ne 'Recovery') })
   {
      $sendMailArgs['Body'] += ($volumes | ConvertTo-Html -Head $htmlHead -PreContent "<H3>Server basic information for [$($Machine)</H3><HR><BR>") -join "`r`n"
   }
   
   if ($ResultEvents)
   {
      Write-Host "`t`tFound $($ResultEvents.Count) total ..." -ForegroundColor Green
      $sendMailArgs['Body'] += "<H3>Total [$($ResultEvents.Count)]</H3>" + ($ResultEvents | ConvertTo-Html -Head $htmlHead) -join "`r`n"
   }
   
   if ($services)
   {
      $sendMailArgs['Body'] += "<BR><H3>Server Services <br /></H3>" + ($services | ConvertTo-Html -Head $htmlHead) -join "`r`n"
   }
   
   if (($volumes) -and ($ResultEvents) -and ($services))
   {
      # Footer Details
      
      $sendMailArgs['Body'] += "<BR> For more Information, please open the website http://support.domain.com </U></B><BR><HR>"
      
      $sendMailArgs['Subject'] = "$($machine) [$((Resolve-DnsName -Name $Machine -Type A).IPAddress)] Server Status result as of $(Get-Date -Format 'F')"
      
      Send-MailMessage @sendMailArgs      
   }
}
```

The issue with the below script is that it always send out email even when there is nothing to display like in the below screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Which variables? What type do they have? How do you define empty for those types?

Comment: ($volumes) -and ($ResultEvents) -and ($services)

Comment: If they are arrays, you can check them like `$services.Count -gt 0`.

Comment: I've tried using -ne $null but it is still failed, empty email is sent out like the screenshot.

Comment: You could set a variable `$isThereSomethingToEmail = $false` at the start, and only inside the parts where you actually add something into the body with `$sendMailArgs['Body'] += ...` set it to $true. Then replace `if (($volumes) -and ($ResultEvents) -and ($services)) {...}` with `if ($isThereSomethingToEmail) {...}`

Comment: Can you please confirm that you have tried `$sendMailArgs['Body'] -ne $null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that the first `If ($volumes | ...` is not just testing if `$volumes` is *something*, but there it depends if the freespace is lower than a certain warning value.

Later, with `if (($volumes) -and ($ResultEvents) -and ($services)) {...}` you do not test `$volumes` the same way, so there could be nothing written in the body there.

I would suggest adding a new (boolean) variable on top

```
$isThereSomethingToEmail = $false
```

and set that to $true inside each `if()` only when the if succeeds and you actually add a line to the body, just before or after `$sendMailArgs['Body'] += ...`

Then finally simply test for this variable

```
if ($isThereSomethingToEmail) {
    # finish the splat and send the email
}
```

Comment: yes, you are so right to the point :-)
many thanks as usual for your great support.